# How to check if the array of attributes from xml node contains the desired value?

Tags: arrays, xml, groovy

Colleagues, i have Node in xml (response of web service) which looks like:

```
<ns:addresses>
    <ns:address>
                <ns:addressType>PlaceOfRegistration</ns:addressType>
                 <ns:regionName>NewZeland</ns:regionName>
    </ns:address>
    <ns:address>
                   <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
                   <ns:regionName>Africa</ns:regionName>

    </ns:address>
</ns:addresses>
```

I need to check:

1. if the LivingPlace exists among address
2. regionName in LivingPlace address is not null

I have some attempts to check it but without success because I do not have enough experience in the Groovy.
My code is:

```
def addressNodeCount = resp.getDomNodes("//ns:address//ns:addressType").size();
log.info "Count: " + addressNodeCount; 

//1 attempt
for (def nodeIndex = 1; nodeIndex <=  addressNodeCount; nodeIndex++) {
   def node = resp.getDomNodes("//ns:address//ns:addressType")
   node.each { 
      log.info "node " + nodeIndex + " - " + it.firstChild.nodeValue
   }
}

//2 attempt
for( item in resp.getDomNodes("//ns:address//ns:addressType"))
log.info "Item : [$item]"
```

Could you help?

**UPDATE1**

Full xml web service response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:getPerson xmlns:ns="http://test.webservice.namespace">
         <ns:person>
            <ns:address>
               <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
               <ns:regionName>Africa</ns:regionName>
            </ns:address>
            <ns:address>
               <ns:addressType>PlaceOfRegistration</ns:addressType>
               <ns:regionName>NewZeland</ns:regionName>
            </ns:address>
            <ns:address>
               <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
               <ns:regionName>Europe</ns:regionName>
            </ns:address>
         </ns:person>
      </ns:getPerson>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: are you getting this as an XML string or is it an object that you've printed out? if it's an object, what's its class? I don't want to have to convert to string then back to an object if there's a way to use the existing response object.

Comment: I receive this xml as def webServiceResponse = new XmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContentAsXml).

Comment: If you're happy to use the XML from `messageExchange.responseContentAsXml` and ignore XmlHolder, you can use my answer with only minor changes. I'll update my answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the item as a Node, then you should just be able to do:

```
yourNode.'address'.findAll { it.'addressType' == 'LivingPlace' && it.'regionName'.size() > 0 }
```

Here's a working example using XmlSlurper, with extra items to illustrate `regionName` element being set or not.

```
import groovy.util.XmlSlurper

class ParseXml {

    def static main(args) {
        new ParseXml().parse("""\
            |<ns:addresses xmlns:ns='http://foo.com'>
            |   <ns:address>
            |       <ns:addressType>PlaceOfRegistration</ns:addressType>
            |       <ns:regionName>NewZeland</ns:regionName>
            |   </ns:address>
            |   <ns:address>
            |       <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
            |       <ns:regionName>Africa</ns:regionName>
            |   </ns:address>
            |   <ns:address>
            |       <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
            |       <ns:notRegionName>Foo</ns:notRegionName>
            |   </ns:address>
            |   <ns:address>
            |       <ns:addressType>LivingPlace</ns:addressType>
            |       <ns:regionName>Europe</ns:regionName>
            |   </ns:address>
            |</ns:addresses>
            |""".stripMargin())
    }

    def parse(xml) {
        def s = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml).declareNamespace(ns:'http://foo.com')
        s.'address'.findAll{ it.'addressType' == "LivingPlace" && it.'regionName'.size() > 0 }.each { n ->
            println n.'regionName'
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Africa
Europe
```

**EDIT**

Based on your update, the following will parse the xml string `messageExchange.responseContentAsXml` again using `XmlSlurper` rather than `XmlHolder`:

```
    def parse2(xml) {
        GPathResult result = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)

        result.with {
            declareNamespace(ns:   "http://test.webservice.namespace")
            declareNamespace(soap: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")
        }
        result.'Body'.'getPerson'.'person'.'address'.findAll{ it.'addressType' == "LivingPlace" && it.'regionName'.size() > 0 }.each { n ->
            println n.'regionName'
        }
    }
```

If you require a solution with XmlHolder then [look at the API here](http://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/support/xmlholder.html). Your initial `.getDomNodes()` call is returning an array, rather than a NodeList, so they are slightly different ways of doing the XML searching and parsing.

Comment: nitpicking, but you don't need your property names in quotes ;-)

Comment: ha :) i always use them as i've been caught out with code that had hyphenated element names which do need quoting

Comment: Hm... this code **def node = webServiceResponse.getDomNodes("address")
node.'address'.findAll { it.'addressType' == 'LivingPlace' && it.'regionName'.size() > 0 }.each { n -> log.info n.'regionName'}** does not print RegionName content. ( What i do wrong?

Comment: what is the class of node? `log.info node.getClass()`

Comment: Error *No such property: n for class*

Comment: sorry, changed my comment. I'm interested in your code that generates your version of `node` and finding out what the class is. what is `webServiceResponse`? I want to locally create the same objects and update my answer

Comment: I've update my answer. If the responseContentAsXml is a string this will work.